# Split string after no of characters using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How to split a string using sql after no of characters and add a delimeter?.I know we can do it with procedure or function but is this possible using sql alone?.Thanks in Advance

```
value from DB Column    : aaaaabbbbbcccccdddddeeeee
Result to be from Query : aaaaa-bbbbb-ccccc-ddddd-eeeee
```

**column values can be :**

```
asdhfaskjdfhasjkdfhaskjdfhaskjdfhaskjdfhasdkfjhsadkfhskadfh
ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
asdlfjas aslkdfjasld f laskdfjaslkdf l lskadfjasld fasdfsadfas lasdfjasdf
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 2222222222222222222222
```

Comment: Do your values have always the same length?. If yes, you could use  substring for cut from 1 to 5 add script then from 6 to 10 and so on

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Oracle 11g.

Comment: @JCalcines, Thanks for reply please check the quesion I updated.Length may vary.but alway I want to split based on every five chars.

Comment: is there a maximum length? what is the field definition?

Comment: Thanks for all your kind help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really want to split the string every X characters; it would be more correct to phrase it as wanting to insert a specific character (in this case `-`) every X characters. That should be pretty straight forward to do using the [REGEXP_REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm) function; the documentation has an example of inserting a space after every (non-null) character. Adapting that, something like this should work (though I'm not in a position to test it):

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(your_column, '(.....)', '\1-') "YOUR_COLUMN_ALIAS"
```

Comment: What about removing terminating minus sign?